# Finding the End Coordinates of 2 DrawArc instances and drawing a line to "Close" it

Tags: c#, .net, pdfsharp

So, I am not very proficient in C#/.Net/PDFSharp functions and I cannot seem to find any suitable answer to solve my issue.
Basically, I have a simple program that has to draw contour of an object(it can be curved and etc.) from user input. 
I have Radius and Degrees of an angle to draw 2 arc lines.
In 360 degrees one circle radius is smaller by X amount of thickness that user inputs so the "inside" of the two circles is the same thickness as the whole draft.
Finally, the thing I need the program to do is to draw two lines, on the 2 sides of the arc lines to "connect them" to make it a proper contour, I can manage the starting Line easily enough since it is not dynamic however the End line is dependent on Radius and degrees of an angle.
How do I properly find the End coordinates I suppose, of the Arcs, so that it successfully draws the End line at the end regardless of the Users inputted Radius/Thickness/Angle.
Here is some code for how I drawn the Arcs, the Start line and my failure try of finding the End line (which just draws the line too far from the whole draft).
Input is User Control where User can input the variables (needed multiple but ended up with one, so it sounds  waste to use User Control + Form window).
mmradius, thickness, mmangle are all user inputs, Innerradius is the innercircle radius.

```cs
var innerradius = Input.mmradius- Input.thickness;
gfx.DrawArc(pen, start_x, start_y, mmradius*2, mmradius*2, 0, mmangle);

gfx.DrawLine(pen, start_x + mmradius+ innerradius, start_y + mmradius,
 (start_x + mmradius) + mmradius, start_y + mmradius);

gfx.DrawArc(pen, (start_x + mmradius) - innerradius,
 (start_y + mmradius) - innerradius, innerradius*2, innerradius*2, 0, mmangle);

var CenterX = start_x + mmradius;
var CenterY = start_y + mmradius;
double degrees = mmangle * (Math.PI / 180);
var end_x = mmradius + CenterX * Math.Cos(degrees);
var end_y = mmradius + CenterY * Math.Sin(degrees);

gfx.DrawLine(pen, end_x, end_y, end_x - innerradius, end_y - 2);
```

Hope it's understandable of what I want if not I'll try my best to clarify!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it works better like this:

```
var end_x = CenterX + mmradius * Math.Cos(degrees);
var end_y = CenterY + mmradius * Math.Sin(degrees);
```

Cannot try to run it, so maybe some more changes are needed.

Comment: ...I can't believe that such mix up of variables that I did not notice for few days fixed the issue...
Yup seems to be perfectly locking one end of the DrawLine to the correct spot, if it's like this I'm sure I can fix the other one now that I know that it was just bad formula for the end coordinates search.
Thank you very much even though it was such a silly mistake of mine!